# Adapting/Modifying SharePoint 2010 List WebParts

Tags: sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I've created a page on a SharePoint site that hosts a number of web parts.  One is a custom web part I've written and then three standard list web parts.  The question is I have is that my web part pulls data from the lists behind the list web parts, so if I use the list web parts to say add a new item it doesn't show in the drop-downs on my custom web part, so I have to refresh the page for it to show up.

Is there any way to get the list web parts to trigger an event in my web part so it automatically refreshes?  I tried to see if I can' easily recreate the list web part as a visual web part and then extend it but can't see how to easily achieve that.

Any suggestions would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the webpart in an update panel?

Comment: Thanks @Luis, not sure how to do that to be honest!